# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, cpanel

**I moved my site from one host to another, and both are on Cpanel, but when I open the site I get this error**

```
CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8
Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [MySQLi]: Access denied for user '****'@'localhost' (using password:YES)
```

And when I accessed the site via SSH and typed this command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOUE9.png)

I moved the old database to the new site, and when I finished the transfer there were
many problems, especially with the mysql database

```
Here are the pictures of the site errors
```

1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jy2W.png)
2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlsl4.png)
3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3w4J.png)
4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhKkm.png)
5
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnCFA.png)
6
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0UPh.png)
7
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVxdz.png)

Comment: Did you create a database and MySQL user in the new Host?

Comment: You've taken the [tour] yet you still ignore some of the key guidelines. There are many, many questions like this on this site. Did you search first? Also, don't post code and errors as images. They can't be searched or reproduced easily for testing or part of an answer. Please, see [ask]

Answer (score -2):

`Access Denied for user '****'@'localhost' (using Password: YES)`
itself shows where you're wrong! Have you tried creating a new MySQL user and granting privileges to that user?

It's not even a database problem!!! Either your password is wrong, or user privileges missing over database or user itself does not exist. Try going in cPanel > MySQL Databases first...